# IOS: Passing data back between custom view controller and view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

I have two view controllers.
First one is Custom view controller that loads the images from asset library.
Second view controller shows the full size of selected image with cancel & Delete button

I have used the below code for delete the selected image from custom view controller.
customviewcontroller.m

```
-(void)deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)itemPaths
{
//here i want to control the delete option when cancel pressed
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSIndexPath *itemPath in itemPaths) {
[indexSet addIndex:itemPath.row];
}
[self.selectedAssets removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
}
/* call the delete function*/
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSArray *selectedItemsIndexPaths = [self.collectionview1 indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    [self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];
    [self.collectionview1 deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];
    }
```

This working fine for delete the selected image from custom view controller.
but It works also cancel. Now, I want to control deletion on cancel.
kindly help me to solve this.

I have already tried using button tag for identify which button was pressed. but can't control in custom vc
secondview.m

```
- (IBAction)CancelPhoto:(id)sender{
 [Cancel setTag:1]; //set tag value at cancel
}
```

Comment: Choose solution from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to pass date between view controllers. I'm giving you a very simple solution as per your requirements:

Assuming you have all your images in a mutable array in first view controller.

```
NSMutableAray *imagesArray;
```

Make a property images array of NSMutableArray type in second view controller.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableAray *imagesArray;
```

assign your array to property while pushing/presenting view

```
secondController.imagesArray = imagesArray;
```

On delete event remove that image from array.

```
[self.imagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
```

dismiss/pop your second view where ever you want and refresh your first view controller in *viewWillAppear* of *viewDidAppear* method.

As you have passed reference of your main images array, both classes (view controllers) share same array through pointer and a change in array from either side will be reflected in both screens

Answer (score 0):

There are  3 ways (in my opinion):

1. Delegate
2. Notification
3. In case: you are using database, just remove image url and reload data